# Unable to access model property inside a controller- MVC 5

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-editor

I am fairly new to MVC. Trying to implement Kendo editor functionality. I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which returns the saved response which is of type string. In the backend it is saved as a html content with the tags. I have created a model with below properties. I am trying to use the same property in the controller, but somehow I am unable to access the property in the controller not sure why. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Model:

```cs
public class LargetextQuestion
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```cs
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Largetext()
        {


            HsipLargetextQuestionViewModel vm = new HsipLargetextQuestionViewModel();

            var result = hsiplargetextquestionrepository.GetLargeTextdata(cRegion, cStateCode, nFY, reportId, sectionId, subsectionId, displayNumber, questionNumber, questionPartNumber, userId);


            vm.Response = result;

            return View(vm);

[HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Largetext(HsipLargetextQuestionViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {


          hsiplargetextquestionrepository.SaveLargetextResponse(cRegion, cStateCode, nFY, reportId, sectionId, subsectionId, displayNumber, questionNumber, questionPartNumber, responseString, userId);

            return Content("Saved");
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Viewmodel:

```cs
 private IHsipLargetextQuestionsrepository hsiplargetextquestionrepository;

        #region Properties
        [Required]
        [AllowHtml]
        [MaxLength(500, ErrorMessage = "You must enter less than 500 characters.")]
        public  string Response { get; set; }
        public decimal QuestionNumber { get; set; }
        #endregion


        public HsipLargetextQuestionViewModel()
        { }

        public HsipLargetextQuestionViewModel(IHsipLargetextQuestionsrepository repo)
        {
            this.hsiplargetextquestionrepository = repo;


        }
```

When i do a save the record doesn't get saved and updated to the database. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Thank you,
Hari

Comment: Do you have any specific errors?

Comment: It all depends on what your _GetLargeTextdata_ method is returning. Is it returning strongly typed resutl?

Comment: I am editing my original post with changes. Now the issue is different, I am unable to return view it is throwing a routin g related error

Comment: Are you intentionally not using the Razor View engine? Right click `View` in your controller and then `Go To View` and see where it takes you.

Comment: Thanks!! Steve that fixes the issue. I fixed the view part routing and it is done.

Comment: Also, on HTTPPOST I have to save the response as a string which inserts a  record in a table in the backend. I will edit my original code and post the HTTPPOST part of it. Can someone please point my mistake. Why I am unable to save the data (postback) into the db. thanks

Comment: You are referring to cRegion, cStateCode, etc. Where are these declared? What you would typically do is pass an Id into the GET, fetch the record, fill your viewmodel, show it in the view. Then when you submit your form the viewmodel will be updated so you update (or add) based on that.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for quick reply. As of now, I am hardcoding all the values will change them later. How do I pass the id into get? Can you please give me an example. Also, I am adding my viewmodel to the post above for you to look at. Thansk

Comment: Here is a basic example https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view